# From Database to array to string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select data from my database and display it like a string. I know you would need to change it to an array and then to a string, but I don't know how. When I run the mysql query:

```
"SELECT 'plant (cm)' FROM PlantDATA"
```

I get the following:

```
0.10
0.25
0.33
```

I really would like to get it to a string like:

```
0.10, 0.25, 0.33
```

so I could feed it to my bootstrap chart.

EDIT: My database looks like this: {id, date, plant (cm)}

```
1 | 01-02-2019 | 0.10
2 | 03-02-2019 | 0.25
3 | 06-02-2019 | 0.33
```

Comment: See `implode()`.

Comment: Note that plant is not a function.

Comment: I changed it, because the column is called 'plant (cm)' instead of 'plant' and '(cm)'.

Comment: Note that 'plant (cm)' is a string

Comment: 'plant (cm)'   seems a literal sting  .. explain better your question

Comment: You need mysql `GROUP_CONCAT` e.g `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(plant (cm)) FROM PlantDATA`

Comment: @Mr.Plopkoek Show us how exactly are you retrieveing the data from the database. Then we will be able to come up with an solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda solved my own question by surfing on the internet. So here's my working code:

```
// Get the 'water (cm)' from database to chart
            $query="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`plant (cm)` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM PlantDATA ORDER BY date";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            foreach($result as $category) { }

            $res_arr = implode(',',$category);
            //print_r($res_arr);
```

I used the GROUP_CONCAT so I get an output like this:
`0.1, 0.25, 0.33` (already from running the query).
Then execute the query and with foreach save it in one, then implode it as others were saying (and the `print_r($res_arr);` at the end was just for debugging purposes.

In the chart area I used the `print_r($res_arr);` in php formation and it worked!

So Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion  ..  If you want select a column named 'plant (cm)' then you should use backtics

```
 "SELECT `plant (cm)` FROM PlantDATA"
```

and if you want comma separated  result you could use group_concat

```
"SELECT group_concat(`plant (cm)`) FROM PlantDATA"
```

Comment: If this is *Just a suggestion* - surely a comment would be better.  If this solves the problem then it is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: .. i don't know your data content so  i can't eval your result  .. update yuor question add  a clear data sample and  the expected result

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I used group_concat like you said (with some other code) and it's working!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, but it only helped partially. I had to add more code to let it work, so you didn't actually solve my issue. I am still thankfull tho!